# How does parsing a c# date to be a javascript date even work with the ')'?

Tags: javascript, c#

I know that to convert a C# date, like `/Date(1430341152570)/` to a JavaScript date, it's the following:

```
var part = "/Date(1430341152570)/".substr(6); // => "1430341152570)/"
var jsDate = new Date(parseInt(part));
```

My question: how is the `part` value, which includes a trailing `)/` able to be parsed into an int via `parseInt`? Wouldn't JS throw an error on trying to convert something that has the `)/` characters? It would make more sense to me if the `part` value was something like `"/Date(......)/".substr(6).replace(')/','')` b/c at least you're making it a string of #'s to be parsed to an int.

Comment: In what way is `/Date(1430341152570)/` a "C# date"? (It may be how one particular JSON serializer chooses to serialize `DateTime`, but that's almost certainly just to emulate some other representation... and it's far from the only representation JSON serializers can use.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

`)` isn't a numeral, so everything from there onwards is ignored as specified.

Or from the [ES6 draft standard](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-parseint-string-radix):

> `parseInt` may interpret only a leading portion of string as an integer value; it ignores any code units that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an integer, and no indication is given that any such code units were ignored.

Comment: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-parseint-string-radix - in particular, see the *note*

Comment: @RussCam: Thanks, will link to and quote that too.